# Setting Up Mturk for external questions

Tags: mechanicalturk

I have a website in which i used D3.js to generate random sets of stimuli for which the recruited MTurk workers will perform tasks. I want to recruit workers using MTurk tasks, using which I will redirect them to my website for actual work. I am fairly new to mturk and have the following questions.

How do I direct mturk to my external website? Do i need to write some script in my website?

when the workers finish the task, how do i collect the data? I have my website communicating to a database server where i am hoping to collect my data for each task. Are we allowed to collect data in this manner or we have to follow any protocol?

Any suggestions and comments based on your experiences and insights in using MTurk would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either provide a simple HTMLQuestion page with a link to your site (where you host the task and record your data) or you can have a true ExternalQuestion HIT where your side is displayed in an iframe inside the MTurk website and data are recorded on either your, on MTurk, or both.

In the former case, it's typical to provide some kind of completion code that workers will enter in the HIT to receive compensation. In the latter, you simply have to submit the AssignmentId attached to each HIT (plus one other form field) back to the MTurk server as a form POST.

Comment: Hi Thomas, Thank you for the reply. I would prefer to setup the former one where i can provide a link my site. Can you tell me how do i provide a completion code to workers once they are done. I guess i need to write some script in my html page for that. It would be really helpful if you can guide me to some template that i can use it.

Comment: The standard thing is then to just supply a text form field in the HIT where the worker can submit the code. You can generate the code on your own site however you want - some kind of server-side script that generates a random number, some javascript, etc. The code can be whatever you want it to be, it's just a mechanism to prevent scammers (rare though they may be) from attempting to get paid despite not doing any actual work.